# How to add words to english model word list in Julius Speech Recognition Engine?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp

I want to add some English words to model but how can I achieve this ?

https://github.com/julius-speech/julius

Answer (score 0):

That is probably not possible since that is model is designed for prediction only. It is not designed for [training](https://github.com/julius-speech/julius/issues/176).